# PHP queue fail safe

Tags: php, queue

Currently have a queue system setup using something like amazon's queue service. Right now I am using supervisor to keep the workers from quitting.

Trying to provide a front end point that can take in 500-2K reqs/sec and need the data to get captured through the queue. Sometimes the queue services[https based] goes down, I am currently running beanstalkd as a backup queue that takes the same data and sends to a separate group of workers and stores that data in a separate database but with the same table structure as the main db.

The idea is I would take the data from the backup and compare it against the expected actual data and audit it, any differences would be reported and possibly added into the expected dataset.

Does this seem like a practical approach to this problem as I am trying to make sure we capture 99.99% of the data coming in.

Small "demonstration" below to help give you a picture.

```
Endpoint A -- collects data(
    Queue1[amazon type queue]
    Queue2[beanstalkd]
)

Queue1 Worker sends data to DB1[used for reports]
Queue2 Worker sends data to DB2[storage --expect to have all data]

Audit Process compares data from DB2 to DB1 and reports the differences
If differences captured, tries to add them to DB1
```

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Why wouldn't php suffice for something like this if I am able to get the data to the queues and into the databases fairly easily

Comment: PHP would work but only on a small scale. On a large scale I would lean more towards a programming language with a dash of web programming. There's much better languages that would keep bandwidth usage and server stress to a more manageable state. C++, C#, Java, .NET, take your pick.

Comment: @bobthyasian let's say I implemented the design above but with a different language...While php may not be the best langauge in the long run, trying to see if how I am handling the queue failure in a manner that makes sense

Comment: Where are these uneducated opinions coming from? Both Gerald and bobthyasian are completely wrong and this isn't coming from because I'm a PHP fan boy. @BrianPutt - please ignore these comments that have  0 facts to back those opinions up, I'm running a huge scale queue based on PHP / ZeroMQ (and it's performing better than Java solutions we tried). When it comes to actual question - I can't answer it properly because I wouldn't design the messaging that way. However, what I wanted to say is that if you want to use PHP - use it.

Comment: @N.B. thanks, would you be able to shed light on how you might setup a queue system that has a fallback plan if queue1 is down

Comment: You build in redundancy in sense of having multiple physical locations storing the same data. With ZeroMQ it's easy to achieve such topology. If one node is down, there are N other nodes doing its job. I tried to use Amazon's SQS but I didn't like it, same goes for beanstalk (that's just a personal preference, nothing to do with actual software, from what's available - both are great pieces of software). However, if you *really* need the data to come trough - you will have to build the topology with redundancy in mind, same like RAID arrays work.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks for the insight, will look into alternatives, just need to read up on some articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to take N.B's comments and apply a different model. I had a primary queue service and a secondary. If the first one sent a null or bad http response, I would then send the message to a backup queue. The queue worker would pull from both sources and run them appropriately.

Here's a small diagram of what it ended up being so you can see the difference between the original idea and the final one....

```
Endpoint A -- collects data(
    Queue1[amazon type queue]
    Queue2[amazon2 type queue]
)

Queue1 Worker sends data to DB1[used for reports]

If Queue1 fails, it auto sends data to Queue2, 
If Queue2 fails, it stores in database for later retrieval
```